# Syntax Error When Writing a Multi-Dimensional Array to Excel File

Tags: ruby, excel, rubygems, osx-elcapitan

I am attempting to write a multi-dimensional array to an Excel file (extension `.xls`) using the [WriteExcel](https://rubygems.org/gems/writeexcel) Ruby gem on El Capitan.

My attempt:

```
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-
require 'writeexcel'

# Create a new Excel workbook
workbook = WriteExcel.new('ruby.xls')

# Add a worksheet
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet

eec =  [
  ['maggie', 'milly', 'molly', 'may'  ],
  [13,       14,      15,      16     ],
  ['shell',  'star',  'crab',  'stone']
  ]

worksheet.write_col('A1', \@eec)

workbook.close
```

The error I get:

```
iMac:scrapScripts guy$ ruby script.rb
script.rb:16: syntax error, unexpected $undefined, expecting ')'
worksheet.write_col('A1', \@eec)
                           ^
```

Using the gem documentation found [here](http://writeexcel.web.fc2.com/en/doc_en.html#write_col).

Can anyone explain why this syntax error is occurring, and how I can fix it?

Comment: The docs are ported from Perl, and apparently still contain a lot of the Perl sigils.

Comment: @DavidK-J Knowing this should help me in the future.  Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove garbage symbols from the call to `write_col`:

```
- worksheet.write_col('A1', \@eec)
+ worksheet.write_col('A1', eec)
```